# shell script for sleeping 1 week

Tags: unix, ksh, unix-timestamp

Can anyone give me the script for 'sleep a job for entire week' as a shell command.

Before sleeping in every run it should calculate the next week's date and time.

I found something which was bit useful

```
startTime=$(date +%s) 

endTime=$(date -d "next week" +%s)

timeToWait=$(($endTime- $startTime)) sleep $timeToWait
```

Comment: which part is not usefull? in other words, what is not working for you?

Comment: Sleeping for 1 week or sleeping until start of next week?

Comment: the job will be like 1.after sleep it will excute some comands 2.it will clculalte the next weeks time 3.sleep until next week      this scenario should be automated

Comment: If the sleep is interrupted and this does not kill the shell/script, the script would continue as if the wait time had past.  This approach should *always* include additional tests to verify that the _time is right_.

Comment: For reference, sleeping for a week is rarely (i'd argue "never") useful.  That's the kind of thing cron was made for; it'll run your script every week for you if you tell it to. Just make the script do those commands you want to run every week, and don't bother sleeping.  `man crontab` for details, in Linux.  As for other *nixes, i couldn't tell you where the docs are.

Answer (score 4):

```
date -d "next week"
```

is a different way to say

```
date -d "7 days"
```

This means "seven days from now", which is *not* the start of the next week and is also probably not what you want. If it *is* what you want and you are using [`GNU sleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep), you can just issue this command:

```
sleep 7d
```

to have your script sleep for seven days. If you are not using GNU sleep, then you will have to convert the seven day interval to seconds:

```
sleep 604800
```

If you want the *start* of the next week, then this might be of help in `ksh`, or even in `bash`:

```
let time=`date -d "next monday" +%s`-`date +%s`
sleep $time
```

That said, I think that you are using the wrong tool for this job. Having a script `sleep` for seven days is quite impractical - any number of things could happen in the mean time, from the system rebooting to the shell process being killed.

You should look at [`crond`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/crond) and [`crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab), [`atd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/atd) and [`at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) or even at a more modern `cron` variant/supplement, such as [frcon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fcron) or [anacron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron).

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why do you require a 1 week sleep?

I ask because if you want a process to wait for a week and then retry/ do something, cron job may be better. For 2 reasons -->

1) Save resources

2) If for some reason your system has to be restarted/ goes down - your shell script will stop and whatever you were waiting for will not happen.

Whereas a cron job will run exactly when you want it to run saving you from such a scenario. Some useful examples are in the link below

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

I learned of this because I experienced it myself! :)

Answer (score 0):

`coreutils` `sleep` supports the `d` postfix so:

```
sleep 7d
```

Will sleep 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

I warned against a single long wait, and I would not do this with a waittime of 1 week.
But I have used variations of this in the past:

```
 waittime=
 interval=

 : ${waittime:?specify wait time in seconds}
 : ${interval:?specify interval in seconds}

 t0=SECONDS
 target=$(( t0 + waittime ))

 until
     (( SECONDS > target ))
 do
     sleep $interval
 done
```